# Best way to store list of items and properties within another list of items

Tags: c#

I need to store a list of items entered by the user. These items can have several classifications associated with them, and those classifications can have their own properties. What would be the best way to store data in this manner?

Just for an example I'll use cars. The user enters they have a Ford. Then the user specifies which Ford cars they have (could be Mustang, Focus, etc). Then enters the cost for that Mustang, Focus, or whatever. So we would end up with a list of Ford cars each with their own cost.

Then the user will enter GM and start another list of the same type. 
This is how I'm seeing the list:

```
Ford -> Mustang -> $30000
     -> Focus -> $20000
     -> F150 -> $40000

GM -> Camaro -> $30000
   -> Corvette -> $50000
```

I thought about using nested arrays but that doesn't seem like an efficient way to handle this because it looks like I'd have to nest 3 arrays deep. If I do an array of objects I will have to duplicate the manufacturer for each car (using my example) and I only want the user to see one entry for each manufacturer.

Comment: is this not just a list of objects with three properties each: make, model, and price?

Comment: Use a class for car with brand,model and price. Then use a `List<car>` to add all them. Having this list, after you can group by anything,display data in the way you want...

Comment: You have to split model from view. You have Entities with Properties => Makes a good candidate for a class. Then you have the view. That's a whole different story. You could group by one the properties for example ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do something simple with a Car model and then a CarView model to provide a list of cars that you can display as required.

```
    public class Car
    {
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

    public class CarView
    {
        public List<Car> CarList { get; set; } 
    }
```

You can then populate the CarList with a series of cars and display the ones you want:

```
        var mustang = new Car
        {
            Brand = "Ford",
            Model = "Mustang",
            Price = 30000.00M
        };

        var focus = new Car
        {
            Brand = "Ford",
            Model = "Focus",
            Price = 20000.00M
        };

        var corvette = new Car
        {
            Brand = "GM",
            Model = "Corvette",
            Price = 50000.00M
        };

        CarView dealerCars = new CarView()
        {
            CarList = new List<Car>()
        };           
        dealerCars.CarList.Add(mustang);
        dealerCars.CarList.Add(focus);
        dealerCars.CarList.Add(corvette);

        var filteredList = dealerCars.CarList.Where(item => item.Brand == "Ford");

        foreach(var car in filteredList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Brand: {0}, Model: {1}, Price: ${2}", car.Brand, car.Model, car.Price);                
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: This is working for me, I just need to figure out how to databind it to a listview now and only display one property. But that's another question for another time.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to create your own class/struct for your object :

```
public class Car
{
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
var carsDict = new Dictionary<string, List<CarDetails>>()
{
   { "Ford", new List<CarDetails>() },
   { "GM", new List<CarDetails>() },
};

var mustang = new CarDetails
{
    Brand = "Ford",
    Model = "Mustang",
    Price = 30000
}

carsDict["Ford"].Add(mustang);
carsDict["Ford"].Add(new CarDetails { Brand="Ford", Model="Focus", Price=20000 });
```

If you want to get let's say all Ford cars you can simply get the list :

```
var allFords = carDicts["Ford"];
```